# Matrix Sorting mergesort C

Tags: c, sorting, quicksort, mergesort

I have this problem where I have to sort a matrix like:

```
0 0 4
1 0 3
0 1 4
1 1 5
0 2 3
1 2 4
```

to:

```
1 0 3
0 2 3
0 0 4
0 1 4
1 2 4
1 1 5
```

So rows stay the same, from smaller to bigger per columns as shown in the example. Matrix will always have 3 columns and x rows.

I already tried Insertion Sorting this and despite working it is not efficient and takes to much to run given the amount of rows in the real application.

I'll provide a small code of what I pretend:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int abc[6][3] = {
        { 0, 0, 4 },
        { 1, 0, 3 },
        { 0, 1, 4 },
        { 1, 1, 5 },
        { 0, 2, 3 },
        { 1, 2, 4 },
    };

    //
    //sort 
    //

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        printf("%d %d %d\n", abc[i][0], abc[i][1], abc[i][2]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'd like to try both mergesort and quicksort but any help is appreciated.

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Unless you have special requirements, use [the standard `qsort` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort).

Comment: Is the sort order 'increasing element 2, then increasing element 1, then increasing element 0' of each row?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes precisely

Comment: How big is the `x` (number of rows) in the real application?  Thousands, millions, bigger than that?

Comment: up to 100000 rows @JonathanLeffler

Comment: but I'll have to perform this operation several times per application run so performance in this particular step matters.

Comment: You'll be fairly hard-pressed to beat the standard `qsort()`.  However, you could avoid the overhead of function calls for the comparator function if you code your own.  Whether that would outweigh the cost of making a robust enough DIY version is debatable.  I recommend trying the standard `qsort()` and seeing if that's fast enough.  Only if it isn't do you think of writing your own. sort.  Unless, of course, the rules of the exercise mean you can't use the standard `qsort()`.

Comment: I'm fairly new to C could u help me with the sort function? I'm having trouble with it, in the compare function and the calling bit its qsort(abc, sizeof abc, what in here?, compare function)

Comment: Have you looked around SO for "how to use qsort" with the '[c]' tag?  There must be hundreds if not thousands of questions.  A suitable search string might be 'is:q [c] qsort'.

Comment: Well qsort call im sure what im doing now but couldn't find ant compare function that would apply and I'm still confused about it...

Comment: You should use the signature `int comparator(const void *v1, const void *v2)`, and the function can start `{ const int *p1 = v1; const int *p2 = v2;` and then you can compare `p1[2]` with `p2[2]`, etc.

Comment: For 10,000 rows, I timed a system `qsort()` at 1.21 ms; for 100,000 rows, it took 16.5 ms; for 1,000,000 rows, it took 202 ms.  What are your time constraints?

Comment: I'm calling it in main like this `qsort(c, z, sizeof(*c), compare_ints_1);` and my compare function is `int compare_ints_1(const void* a, const void* b)
{
  const int *arg1 = a;
  const int *arg2 = b;
 
  if (arg1[0] < arg2[0]) return -1;
  if (arg1[0] > arg2[0]) return 1;
  return 0;
}`

Comment: and having it there or not results in zero changes to c, my matrix

Comment: The comparator is on the right track — but you need to compare `arg1[2]` with `arg2[2]` first, then compare the subscripts `1`, and end with subscripts `0`, don't you?

Comment: The invocation of `qsort()` should be `qsort(abc, sizeof(abc)/sizeof(abc[0]), sizeof(abc[0]), compare_ints_1);` — using the array name from the question.

Comment: First I compare column 0 then 1 only then column 2. I think. Anyway there is something wrong with the comparator I presented because it should at least do something to the matrix even if not what I pretend. Why is it doing nothing? (its like its not even there program its not crashing or anything)

Comment: and about the correction to qsort() z was already that my bad sorry, forgot to include the bit where I calculated z.

Comment: The problem may be your invocation of `qsort()` — I'm not sure why you switch to `c` as the array name, or what `z` represents.  Using `sizeof(*c)` is the same as `sizeof(c[0])`, so that's OK.  You said that you wanted the sort in 'increasing element 2, increasing element 1, increasing element 0' order — comparing 0 first isn't going to achieve that.

Comment: Maybe you need to edit the question to show the code that isn't doing anything?  There are many ways things could be going wrong; it is hard to be sure from comments.  Please create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
(or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach writing your compare function in one of four ways (two formally proper, but all equivalent <sup>1</sup>). The scary `qsort` prototype `int compare (const void *a, const void *b)` is simply the way C has of passing a pointer to elements of the array to be sorted. Your job is simply to cast back to the correct type before comparing in the function.

The real question is ***"What type pointer is being passed?***

When you answer that it's easy. You are sorting a 2D array by rows. A 2D array is actually an array of 1D arrays. Each pointer passed to compare will be a pointer to a 1D array (the rows)

So each `a` and `b` will be a *pointer to array* of `int [3]`. In your compare function, you will need to cast to a pointer to array of `int [3]` and then dereference once to leave the type as `int [3]` and then compare based on the third element. (but when you access your now type `int [3]` array pointer conversion applies to that array as well, so you simply need to add `2` to your pointer value and dereference to compare by the third element).

You can use the result of two conditional tests to avoid potential overflow which can result from simply returning `b - a` which if `b` is a large negative number and `a` is large (or `b` is a large positive number and `a` a large negative number) will occur if the result exceeds the storage capacity for `int`. So instead, for an ascending sort, you can use:

```
    return (a > b) - (a < b);
```

(for a descending sort, just turn the comparisons around, e.g. `(a < b) - (a > b)`. Try it. Pick any two values for `a` and `b` and compute the result. In the ascending case is `a` is less than `b`, you `return 0 - 1;` (or `-1`), e.g. meaning `a` sorts before `b`)

So what does the compare function look like? Since the formal type for *pointer to array* of `int [3]` is `int (*)[3]`, you can do:

```
int comp (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    int *pa2 = *(int (*)[3])a + 2,
        *pb2 = *(int (*)[3])b + 2;

    return (*pa2 > *pb2) - (*pa2 < *pb2);
}
```

or if you wanted to simply make `int pa2` and not worry about having to dereference the pointer in the comparison, for the second formal cast you could enclose the complete cast of `a` in parenthesis and then just use the `(stuff a)[2]` to access the third integer value directly -- it just makes for a messier looking cast, e.g.

```
int comp (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    int pa2 = (*(int (*)[3])a)[2],
        pb2 = (*(int (*)[3])b)[2];

    return (pa2 > pb2) - (pa2 < pb2);
}
```

(whatever makes the most sense to you)

Then the sorting by the third element of each row in your 2D array is really trivial, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int comp (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    int *pa2 = *(int (*)[3])a + 2,
        *pb2 = *(int (*)[3])b + 2;

    return (*pa2 > *pb2) - (*pa2 < *pb2);
}

int main() {

    int abc[6][3] ={{0,0,4},
                    {1,0,3},
                    {0,1,4},
                    {1,1,5},
                    {0,2,3},
                    {1,2,4}};

    qsort (abc, 6, sizeof *abc, comp);

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
        printf(" %2d %2d %2d\n", abc[i][0], abc[i][1], abc[i][2]);

}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/qsort2d+2
  1  0  3
  0  2  3
  0  0  4
  0  1  4
  1  2  4
  1  1  5
```

Now the last two equivalent ways of writing the compare function casts rely on the successive application of array/pointer conversion and understanding that a pointer to array and the array itself will both point to the same address (but are formally of different types) Formally you have `int (*)[3]` but since you know you simply want the second integer after that address, you can cast the compare pointer `a` and `b` to `int *` and add two. This is equivalent, but does not reflect the formal cast. (you can also enclose the whole cast in parenthesis and use `[2]` as well).

The casts look much simpler in that case, but it can be somewhat less apparent what is actually taking place. I'll leave it to you to try replacing `*(int (*)[3])` in the complete program with `(int *)`. (that will avoid the protracted discussion that will take place in the comments)

Look things over and think through both *"What type pointer is being passed?"* and why use the result of two comparisons instead of just the subtraction as the return in your compare function to avoid overflow. Let me know if you have any further questions.

*Footnotes:*

**1.)** [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the unary `'&'` operator, or is a *string literal* used to initialize an array, an expression that has type *"array of type"* is converted to an expression with type *"pointer to type"* that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.

Comment: Wow that was such a comprehensive answer. Especially the explanation about how to refer to the matrix with pointers from inside the compare function. I still have a question tho. Imagine that now instead of the 3 distinct columns I only wanted to compare columns 0 and 1 (in the same order as the suggested example but completely disregarding column 2). From what I got I would have to change the `*pa2 = *(int (*)[3])a + 2` +2 to +1? Am I right? If that's it my problem is completely solved

Comment: Then just use a `int *pa0` to refer to the 1st column and `int *pa2` for the 3rd column.  You then compare by whatever the primary sort is (e.g. 3rd column) then if the 3rd column are equal you go to the 1st column values for the compare. `qsort` provides total control of the sort to you. You can make the compare do anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

Building on David C. Rankin's answer, there is another issue you must take into consideration: what is the precise sorting order you wish to obtain?

It can be inferred from the example you provide that the third column of the 2D array is the primary key. Yet this is not sufficient to fully specify the sorting order. Here are three possibilities:

1. the order of lines with an identical element in third column does not matter. In this case, there could be many different outputs, all correct.
2. the order of lines with identical elements should be the same as in the original 2D array. For this, you need a stable sorting algorithm, such as `mergesort`, but `qsort` is usually implemented with a mix of Quick Sort and other methods for pathological cases, making it non stable and therefore inappropriate for your purpose.
3. the order of lines with identical elements in column 3 should be determined from the values in the second column, and if these values are also identical, from the values in the first column. The example provided is consistent with this method. (from your response to  Jonathan Leffler's comment, this should be your preference).

`qsort()` is appropriate for methods 1 and 3, but not method 2.

Here is a simpler comparison function for method 1:

```c
int comp2(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const int *pa = a;
    const int *pb = b;

    return (pa[2] > pb[2]) - (pa[2] < pb[2]);
}
```

`comp2` can be used for method 2, but you must call `mergesort()` instead of `qsort()`:

```
mergesort(abc, sizeof abc / sizeof *abc, sizeof *abc, comp2);
```

Here is a comparison function for method 3:

```c
int comp_full(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const int *pa = a;
    const int *pb = b;

    if (pa[2] != pb[2])
        return (pa[2] > pb[2]) - (pa[2] < pb[2]);
    if (pa[1] != pb[1])
        return (pa[1] > pb[1]) - (pa[1] < pb[1]);
    else
        return (pa[0] > pb[0]) - (pa[0] < pb[0]);
}
```

Here is a test program for BSD systems:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int comp_full(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const int *pa = a;
    const int *pb = b;

    if (pa[2] != pb[2])
        return (pa[2] > pb[2]) - (pa[2] < pb[2]);
    if (pa[1] != pb[1])
        return (pa[1] > pb[1]) - (pa[1] < pb[1]);
    else
        return (pa[0] > pb[0]) - (pa[0] < pb[0]);
}

int comp2(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const int *pa = a;
    const int *pb = b;

    return (pa[2] > pb[2]) - (pa[2] < pb[2]);
}

int use_stable_sort = 0;

int main() {
    int abc[][3] = {
        { 0, 0, 4 },
        { 1, 0, 3 },
        { 0, 1, 4 },
        { 1, 1, 5 },
        { 0, 2, 3 },
        { 1, 2, 4 },
    };

    if (use_stable_sort)
        mergesort(abc, sizeof abc / sizeof *abc, sizeof *abc, comp2);
    else
        qsort(abc, sizeof abc / sizeof *abc, sizeof *abc, comp_full);

    for (int i = 0, n = sizeof abc / sizeof *abc; i < n; ++i)
        printf("%d %d %d\n", abc[i][0], abc[i][1], abc[i][2]);

    return 0;
}
```